# Is there a way to get a custom style Geolocate Control for use with React and react-mapbox-gl?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using react-mapbox-gl to implement maps for a web app. The design has the geolocate control colored and shaped differently than the default GeolocateControl provided by the underlying library mapbox-gl. I've looked through the [documentation here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#geolocatecontrol) but cannot find anything about this topic.

I would also consider a library that provides a stylable component that can provide the same functionality as the control.

Comment: Any Idea for change style???

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues today, and I couldn't find any information in the documentation. However, if you open your developer tools, you can inspect and modify the CSS properties. Later, you can apply these changes in your CSS stylesheet. While this might not be the best practice, it was the only solution I could find.

[image]

```
  Example CSS
    .mapboxgl-user-location-accuracy-circle {
      z-index: 100000;
      background-color: #f21d1d33;
    }
```